# Is the second "about" required in "…says as much about you as it does (about) them"?

Tags: prepositions, comparative-constructions

> Deciding whom you choose as your friends says as much about you as it does them.
> ([From a test](http://www2.edu-edu.com.cn/lesson_crs78/self/pub_j_eng2/soft/content/ch_03/ch_03_03.html))

I'm thinking if the sentence is missing a word:

> Deciding whom you choose as your friends says as much about you as it does **about** them.

I think this preposition is indispensable.

Comment: Despite gotube's and Jack O'Flaherty's views, only the second choice is correct because yes, that preposition is indispensable. The fact that failing to use the proper form happens not to make this particular instance meaningless is not relevant in correct English, much less here in English Language Learners.

FYI, the (From a test) link led to something which struck me as perhaps meaningless, clearly not helpful and prolly irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that context, the second "about" is optional. The sentence is a bit easier to understand if it's included, and only advanced English speakers would leave it out.

The context has two phrases joined by the conjunction *as much ... as*. The two full phrases are:

> (it) says [a quantity] about you
> (it) says [a quantity] about them

where the two "[a quantity]" are represented by "as much" and "as".

So the longest possible version (with the long subject simplified to "it") is:

> It [says] as much about you as it [says] about them.

The verb "says" is repeated on both sides of the conjunction, so the second can be left out, and it will still be understood:

> It says as much [about] you as it **does** [about] them.

In this version, the preposition "about" is also repeated on both sides of the conjunction, so it too can be left out:

> It says as much about you as it does ______ them.

In fact, the "it" and "does" are unnecessary as well:

> It says as much about you as them.

Comment: Thanks.  Can I retain "says" but drop "about": Deciding whom you choose as your friends says as much about you as it **says** them.

Comment: @ForOU No, that would be completely ungrammatical. If you leave out the preposition, _does_ is a substitute for _says about_; if you don’t substitute, you need all of it. Though I have to say I agree with you that leaving out the preposition does jar in this case. I have no logical explanation for why this is the case, because I can think of lots of parallel constructions where the preposition **is** optional, but in this particular case, I would never leave it out. I would be much, much more likely to leave out everything except _them_, as in the last version in this answer (“… as them”).

Comment: @user8356: *Whom* is definitely the direct object of "You choose" there, as well as in "Whom do you choose?"

Comment: Write what you want, but to *me*, the variant with the subject repeated, the repeated verb half-dropped (i.e., replaced by an auxiliary), and the preposition not repeated sounds really unpleasant. Then again, I'm not a native speaker

Answer (score 0):

The repeated preposition is not indispensable. Whether you include it in that sentence is a free choice, with no effect on how understandable it is. In a more complicated sentence, you might need to include it to be clear.